# Stop the video on last frame

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using `VideoView` to play a video and have some difficulties to stop it and keep the last frame after video finishes playing. Currently I am stuck with black last frame after video ends.

Is there a way to accomplish that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last frame of a video you can skip to its end by using:

```
video.seekTo(video.getDuration());
```